# How do the reputation scores work?

Tags: support, reputation

I'm stuck: If I look at reputation scores for "week", "month", "quarter", "year" I find for a top scorer like [José Carlos Santos](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/446262/jos%C3%A9-carlos-santos) the reputation scores

- 530, 305, 305, 75.3

For [myself](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1792/hans-stricker?tab=profile) I find

- 30, 30, 30, 1035

even though there was going on a lot in the last weeks.

So what do these numbers mean? How can they decrease from "week" to "month"? Is it explained somewhere? Should it be obvious?

Comment: But why do I have the same 30 rep for "week", "month" and "quarter"? I cannot imagine why, esp. because there was so much going on?

Comment: I did not include this in my answer, since I assume it is not part of the question, but just in case, after the 75.3 there is a k missing. The unit changes.

Answer (score 7):

The numbers refer to the *current* week, month, quarter, year.

Since it is October 1st, month and quarter just cover today (at the moment of asking) and will be equivalent until November.

Yet the week starts on Sunday, so it includes one more day.